# sql query in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I have a sql query something like this:

```
display = pd.read_sql_query("""
SELECT UserId, ProductId, ProfileName, Time, Score, Text, COUNT(*)
FROM Reviews
GROUP BY UserId
HAVING COUNT(*)>1
""", con)
```

Can anyone help me with equivalent code using just pandas?

I tried:

```
cols = ['UserId', 'ProductId', 'ProfileName', 'Time', 'Score', 'Text']
df[cols].groupby('UserId').agg({'UserId':'count'})
```

This is not giving me the output I get from that query.

This is the dataset:
https://www.kaggle.com/snap/amazon-fine-food-reviews
`database.sqlite`

Comment: Why don't just use `.agg('count')` or `.count()`?

Comment: @MichaelO. That still doesn't give me the output that I get from that SQL query.

Comment: By ANSI standards, that is not a valid SQL query as all non-aggregated columns in `SELECT` must be present in `GROUP BY`. You must be running SQLite in non-ANSI mode as this would fail in practically every relational database. In fact, the results of that query is hard to even interpret!

Comment: @Parfait I found the query in a tutorial it is working in my notebook. So do you mean that query is wrong? I am new to SQLite and I couldn't interpret it myself and I was not able to write equivalent in pandas.

Comment: Do you actually get SQLite results with that query? Up until now I thought only MySQL with its infamous `only_full_group_by` mode off allows this invalid query. Please explain what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do it by using groupby and count.

```
df.groupby('UserId').count().reset_index()
```

Comment: I have tried this but it's not giving me the same output as query.

Answer (score 0):

since you haven't given any sample data

Possible answer is

`df[cols].groupby('UserId').count()`

Comment: I have tried this but it's not giving me the same output as sql query.